# Who has the highest official Dragon Ball Z power level?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

I remember Captain Ginyu exclaiming that Goku had a power level of 180,000 in the Ginyu Force arc, but I don't recall a higher scouter being shown/read aloud in any other episode/movie of DBZ (I'm not including Frieza's 1 million bluff).

Does anyone have more information on this from a credible source? If official data is available, I would also want to know the power levels of a regular Super Saiyan, SS2 and SS3 as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure how credible you consider the Dragon Ball Wiki, but they have compiled a list of power levels of most characters mentioned throughout the series, including GT.

The highest power levels in that list would be the old Supreme Kai's at at most 120 billion, while the next largest power level would be Gogeta SSJ4 at 25 billion.

See [here](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_power_levels) for a more exhaustive list.

[image]

Comment: From the image, it seems that Gogeta's power is 2.5 billion.

Comment: @nhahtdh The list states that Gogeta can get a multiplier of 10, making it 25 billion. I don't really remember how he could get the multiplier though.

Comment: So in the series the old supreme kai could have easily squashed evil buu with just one finger or am I understanding this wrongly?

Comment: @Thomas if he wasnt cursed by the old witch for such a long time he might have. But even in his prime he would probably still have lost the same way the others supreme kais did. Fighting is ofcourse more than power level alone, which kid buu proved centuries ago.

Comment: By the end of the series, power levels seem to have grown to the point they don't mean much. I think Vegeta said at one point power levels were pointless because fighters like them could change it at will (such as when they are hiding their presence).